# oracle Stored Procedure to get the sum(balance) given a parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a supplier_product table ( supp_id, prod_id, invoice_id,price) and an invoice table (invoice_id, balance). I tried a stored proc. given (supp_id) it should all the existing invoice_id and display the balance. here's my code:

```
set serverouput on;
create or replace
Procedure SUP_loop
(v_SUPPLIER_ID int   )
AS
  CURSOR c_SUP IS
    select  SUPPLIER_ID , SUPP_INVOICE_ID, balance 
      from SUPPLIER_PRODUCT, supplier_invoice
     where SUPPLIER_ID=v_SUPPLIER_ID 
       and supp_invoice_id.supplier_product=supp_invoice_id.supplier_invoice;
BEGIN
  --LOOP WITH IMPLICIT VARIABLE DECLARED 
  --AUTOMATIC, OPEN FETCH, CLOSE

  FOR v_SUP_data IN c_SUP LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.SUPPLIER_ID) || '   ' || 
                             TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.SUPP_INVOICE_ID) || '   ' || 
                             TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.balance)  );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

the error i am getting is v_sup_data Error(20,31): PLS-00364: loop index variable 'V_SUP_DATA' use is invalid

```
Error(9,74): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "SUPP_INVOICE_ID"."SUPPLIER_INVOICE": invalid identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the field and the table names swapped round the wrong way.

You have...

```
supp_invoice_id.supplier_invoice
```

...where you should have...

```
supplier_invoice.supp_invoice_id
```

:D

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for referring to a column is <>.<>.  So your cursor query needs the join condition to be `supplier_produce.supp_invoice_id = supplier_invoice.supp_invoice_id`, i.e.

```
create or replace
Procedure SUP_loop
(v_SUPPLIER_ID int   )
AS
  CURSOR c_SUP IS
    select  SUPPLIER_ID , SUPP_INVOICE_ID, balance 
      from SUPPLIER_PRODUCT, supplier_invoice
     where SUPPLIER_ID=v_SUPPLIER_ID 
       and supplier_product.supp_invoice_id = supplier_invoice.supp_invoice_id;
BEGIN
  --LOOP WITH IMPLICIT VARIABLE DECLARED 
  --AUTOMATIC, OPEN FETCH, CLOSE

  FOR v_SUP_data IN c_SUP LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.SUPPLIER_ID) || '   ' || 
                             TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.SUPP_INVOICE_ID) || '   ' || 
                             TO_CHAR(v_SUP_data.balance)  );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```